# How to increase storage space in LVM in production

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, mount, lvm

I have my own servers. I want to increase storage space in of LVM where I have database and my website running.
I run **lsblk** and it gives

```
vda                       252:0    0   150G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0 148.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  74.3G  0 lvm  /
```

so I want to take 100G from **VD3** part and give it to  **ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv**

I want to run commands as below

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

these 2 commands are enough to resize LVM  without a problem?